# Divorced woman remarrying her ex-husband

Tags: halacha, marriage, divorce, issur-vheter, zivug-sheini

May a woman, who after receiving a *get* from her husband has relations with another man out of wedlock, remarry her husband?

Answer (score 12):

Both the first relationship and the second one would have to be formal marriages (the kind that requires a Get to dissolve) for the prohibition of remarrying your divorcée to come into effect. ([ShA EH 10:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.10.1?lang=he-en))

> **איזו גרושה מותרת לחזור לבעלה ובו ז סעיפים:**‏
>
> המגרש את אשתו ואח"כ זינתה מותרת לחזור לבעלה:‏
>    ***הגה*** וכן אם זנתה עם הראשון
>   ונתקדשה לשני וגירשה מותרת לחזור לראשון אפי' היתה מיוחדת לו תחילה (תשו'
>   הרא"ש כלל נ"ג ומהר"ם פאדווה סימן י"ט)‏
>    אבל אם נתקדשה לאחר וגירשה או מת
>   אסורה לחזור לראשון‏
>    *ואפילו לא נתגרשה רק מכח קול בעלמא (הרא"ש כלל ה')
>   (וע"ל סימן ו' וע"ל סימן מ"ו סעיף ה' וסעיף ו'):‏*
>
> The one who divorces his wife, and after that she committed adultery,
>   she is permitted to return to her husband. 
>   *Ram''a: And this is also
>   the case if she committed adultery with the first [husband], and she
>   was betrothed to a second [husband], and he divorces her, she is
>   permitted to return to the first [husband], even if she was designated
>   to him first.*
>
>    Shulchan Arukh: But if she was betrothed afterwards and
>   he divorced her, or he died, it is forbidden for her to return to the
>   first [husband].
>    *Ram''a: And even if she was only divorced from the
>   power of a mere rumor.*